# transform.localPosition does not wok in Unity

Tags: unity, vector, transformation, gameobject, spawning

When im breaking fence `GameObject` there should pop up scores, so it works fine. But position of pop up scores is too low, im trying to raise it by `Vector3 offset` on y axis, but it doesn't work. Pop up scores `GameObject` is spawning on the field as a child of destroyed object before fence `GameObject` was destroyed, so that why im using `transform.localPosition` instead of `transform.position`, but I tried everything and it doesnt work at all.

[image]

There is confirmation that scores `GameObject` is child of fence `GameObject`:

[image]

Code for destructible object:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FenceCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator fenceAnim;
    public GameObject popUp;

    public void Start()
    {
        fenceAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();

    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("pla"))
        {
            ShowFloatingText();
            ScoresManager.scores += 10;
            fenceAnim.Play("BlockBroke");
            Destroy(gameObject, 0.17f);
        }
    }

    public void ShowFloatingText()
    {
        Instantiate(popUp, transform.position, Quaternion.identity, transform);
    }
}
```

Code for pop up scores object:

````
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PopUpText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float destroyTime = 2f;
    public Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0, 2f, 0);

    void Start()
    {
        transform.localPosition += offset;
        Destroy(gameObject, destroyTime);
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @liggiorgio I mentioned everything in the topic. If you need details ok. Imagine, I have a 2d sprite(fence), when player hits it, that object should be destroyed in 0.17 seconds, and there should pop up scores as you can see on the picture I have scores at the bottom of sprite, I need increase offset on y axis to move it a little bit up.